# Cannot insert values into database in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have this problem, when I return all values from the form input it all returns values that were filled in. However when I persist into the database under the store method in my controller it insert empty values. Can anyone help me on this? Thank you. Below are my codes.

```
public function store(EnrollmentRequest $request)
{   
    return $request->all();
    return redirect('/enrollment/create');
}
```

As you could see on top, it returns all inputs. However when I persist it on the database it returns only the id and timestamps;

```
public function store(EnrollmentRequest $request)
{   
    $enrollment = Enrollment::create([$request->all()]);
    return $enrollment;  return redirect('/enrollment/create');
}
```

Also here's my enrollment table:

```
    Schema::create('enrollments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('student_id');
        $table->string('subject_description');
        $table->string('subject_code');
        $table->time('schedule');
        $table->string('room_no');
        $table->integer('no_of_units');
        $table->string('section');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

also my subjects table:

```
Schema::create('subjects', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subject_code');
        $table->string('subject_description');
        $table->time('schedule');
        $table->string('room_no');
        $table->integer('no_of_units');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Your help are well appreciated.

```
   protected $table = 'enrollments';

protected $fillable = [
    'subject_code',
    'subject_description',
    'section',
    'schedule',
    'room_no',
    'no_of_units'
];
```

Comment: Can you show us the model for the table?

Comment: Can you try with $enrollment = Enrollment::create($request->all());

Comment: empty values insert on all fields or any specific fields?

Comment: Did you initialize `protected $fillable` Enrollment in model?

Comment: @James I update the information above. Kindly check included Model for Enrollment

Comment: So even when your `$fillable` array contains those fields you are unable to insert your data correctly?

Comment: @Imtiaz Pabel on all values except the id and timestamps. Thanks.

Comment: @James definitely. I cannot figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: @Minhajul Thanks mate. I just solve the problem. And I updated my table name room_number to room_no.

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it you haven't updated the `$fillable` property of the Enrollment model.

As such you are running in to trouble with mass assignment and only the values that are fillable by default, ID and timestamps, are being inserted - the rest are simply ignored.

You need to add to your `$fillable` property for it to include the other fields that you want to have as fillable through mass assignment (i.e when you are running `Enrollment::create([$request->all()]);`).

It should look something like the below:

```
protected $fillable = ['student_id', 'subject_description', 'subject_code', 'schedule', 'room_no', 'no_of_units', 'section'];
```

Comment: thanks also but I solved it already the answer of Minhajul is correct.